# fetch API call being sent multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a recipe app and for some reason my API calls are sent 5 times since I see the data 5 times when in console.log it. This is an issue for me as the API blocks me from sending more than 5 calls a minute and it wont be very UX friendly if the end product has the same issue. Can anyone see where I am going wrong in the below code?

Id and app key is changed. please note that this is componentDidUpdate since I am running it when the state is changed -thus sending a fetch call

```
async componentDidUpdate() {
        let response = await axios.get(
            `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${this.state
                .searchTerm}&app_id=c5e1&app_key=946ddb0f02a86bd47b89433&to=20`
        );
        let data = response.data.hits.map((data) => ({
            name: data.recipe.label,
            src: data.recipe.image,
            source: data.recipe.source,
            url: data.recipe.url,
            healthLabels: data.recipe.healthLabels,
            dietLabels: data.recipe.dietLabels,
            calories: data.recipe.calories,
            totalWeight: data.recipe.totalWeight,
            totalTime: data.recipe.totalTime,
            totalNutrients: data.recipe.totalNutrients,
            ingredients: data.recipe.ingredients
        }));
        this.setState({ recipeResults: data });
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Comment: write the above code in componentDidMount instead of componentDidUpdate

Comment: i need componentDidUpdate because it is dependent on a state update that is made by a click @Supercool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request depends on `this.state.searchTerm`. so if `this.state.searchTerm` is changed your component will make a request.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.searchTerm !== this.state.searchTerm) {
    axios.get(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${this.state.searchTerm}&app_id=c5e1&app_key=946ddb0f02a86bd47b89433&to=20`)
      .then((response) => {
        // process response
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // process error
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm buddy. Can you explain a little bit more about prevProps, prevState and the if statement? Having trouble wrapping my head around how this stopped my request from being sent 5 times

Comment: componentDidUpdate calls every time when state or props was changed. This method get prevProps and PrevState. So if you want to react some changes you have to check what changes were made. `if (prevState.searchTerm !== this.state.searchTerm)`  is true if searchTerm was changed. Magic 

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy Sometimes it is interesting to see how different people use react. Let's assume that you have multiple params in your component`s state and when some of them changes you need to make a data fetch. Are you going to write multiple conditions in ```componentDidMount``` method for every specific parameter?

Comment: In componentDidMount I check if props is exist. In conponentDidUpdate I check if some props or state was changed. But I prefer hooks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are fetching data in `componentDidUpdate` method of the component and using `setState`. It triggers component re-render and the code inside your `componentDidUpdate` executes again and again after every `setState`. Use `componentDidMount` for one time data fetching

Comment: i need componentDidUpdate because it is dependent on a state update that is made by a click @Maksym Bezruchko

Comment: Could you add the snippet of the component?

Comment: Or just the snippet of code where you change ```searchTerm``` value

Comment: You can find it here- https://www.codepile.net/pile/6om5xyo2 Maksym Bezruchko

Comment: afraid this solution didnt fly mate. But I did get the answer here- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020523/12998811 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do api call based on some piece of state being updated you should use either Redux or React context/hooks API. These libraries make it easy to subscribe to some state changes and execute an appropriate action. Ideally you should not do something like fetch in your `componentDidUpdate` as it can be called many times per second
Redux is really fast and time proven but it takes some time to setup and maintain the structure around it. So in your case I would look at `useEffect()` method of React hooks

Comment: Thanks mate. Im just coming to grips with react so this is all kinda new to me. But redux and/or context API is next on my list. which one do you think is best for easier state management? passing state across nested components really bums me out sometimes

Comment: I would suggest putting some time in learning Redux - it is widely used in the industry and it will teach you many things about the state management in large applications. React context/hooks is much easier to setup and once you learn Redux it will be super easy to get along with context/hooks. 
Overall Redux just requires a little bit more work for structuring your code but it does not make it any more harder to use